# Sqoop job to import data from sql server ignores schema

Tags: java, sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

How do I pass a schema name to `sqoop job` importing data from `SQL Server` to `hdfs`?

```
sqoop job --create job_name -- import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;database=datatabase_name;username=user;password=password" --table source_table --as-avrodatafile --target-dir data/target_folder -- --schema schema_name
```

When I execute the job using

```
sqoop job -exec job_name
```

The query that is generated is missing the schema name.

It fails with following error message:

```
15/08/28 10:53:09 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: **SELECT t.* FROM [source_table] AS t WHERE 1=0**
15/08/28 10:53:09 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'source_table'.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'source_table'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:750)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:759)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:269)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1773)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1578)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:228)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:283)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem, and i used the following command instead,

`sqoop job --exec job_name -- -- --schema schema_name`

Comment: Further the schema argument from the  job --create can also be dropped

Answer (score 1):

Piggy backing on Pradeep's answer, here is how I created a job with the schema command inside the job schema:

```
sqoop job --create job_name -- import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;database=datatabase_name;username=user;password=password" --table source_table --as-avrodatafile --target-dir data/target_folder -- -- --schema schema_name
```

Notice that there are three sets of **--** at the end. `-- -- --schema schema_name`

I am using this to automatically create jobs that perform incremental updates. In order to take advantage of sqoop's ability to automatically track the incremental updates, I needed to use a job.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

`sqoop job --create job_name -- import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;database=datatabase_name;username=user;password=password" --table source_table --as-avrodatafile --target-dir data/target_folder -- --schema schema_name --verbose --columns .....list of columns here(comma separated)`