# Sqoop - Use schema in saved job

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hdfs, database-schema, sqoop

When I run this command on shell works fine:

```
sqoop import --incremental append --check-column id_civilstatus --last-value -1 
--connect jdbc:postgresql://somehost/somedb --username someuser 
--password-file file:///passfile.txt --table sometable --direct -m 3 
--target-dir /jobs/somedir -- --schema someschema
```

But when I try to save it as a job:

```
sqoop job --create myjob -- import --incremental append --check-column id_civilstatus 
--last-value -1 --connect jdbc:postgresql://somehost/somedb --username someuser 
--password-file file:///passfile.txt --table sometable --direct -m 3 
--target-dir /jobs/somedir -- --schema someschema
```

Then I execute:

```
sqoop job --exec myjob
```

I get this error message:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: relation "sometable" does not exist
```

This is error due to 'sometable' does not exists in default schema.

Why sqoop job soes not take schema parameter? I am missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify /change **default schema passing** "?currentSchema=**myschema**"in jdbc connection [More detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20220810223928/https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html#connection-parameters) .

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to mention schema separately, you can either keep it in jdbc URL, not sure if postgres jdbc URL have that option or not. You have to add it in the table option itself. Something like below

```
—table schemaName.tableName
```

Comment: This is not an option with sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as your JDBC URL

```
jdbc:postgresql://somehost/somedb/someschema
```

and remove `--schema someschema` from the Sqoop Statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275781/sqoop-job-to-import-data-from-sql-server-ignores-schema).

```
sqoop job --exec myjob -- -- --schema someschema
```